# Combine two Mysql SUM select query to one query

Tags: mysql, sum

I have below two query's SUM the values
**Query1:***

> SELECT SUM(price) FROM TABLE1 WHERE `acc_id` = '555'

**Query2:**

> SELECT SUM(price) FROM TABLE2 WHERE `account` = '555' && active='1'

I try to combine this two query but give wrong sum result , for example if `query1 sum is: -86500` and `Query2 sum is: 76000` , RESULT must be `-10500` but result shown with a number like `-486000`

I'm trying like this, but i'm not getting expected result.

```
SELECT SUM(t1.price + t2.price) AS TotalCredit 
FROM TABLE1 AS t1, TABLE2 AS t2 
WHERE t1.`acc_id` = '555' && t2.`Account`='555' && t2.`Active`='1'
```

Table image : [image]

Comment: You have said nothing about the relation of one table to the other to know how (or if) they can be joined in a meaningful way.  Can you give examples of the data you are trying to sum and talk about why the data is spread across two tables?

Comment: @root try my solution, i'm expecting, you would get your expected result. But, still i'm waiting for your response.

Comment: I add a image of my two table

Comment: Thanks all , problem solved with Akhil answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to join the number of records get duplicated and you get a higher value for sum 
try this

```
SELECT sum(prc) 
FROM (
    SELECT SUM(price) prc FROM TABLE1 WHERE acc_id = '555'
    union all 
    SELECT SUM(price) prc FROM TABLE2 WHERE account = '555' && active='1'
) a
```

Comment: Thanks but Have this error : `Error Code: 1248 \n Every derived table must have its own alias`

Comment: Did you notice the `a` after the inner query?

Comment: :O Thanks man , sorry I left that char ... now work on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24c89 ... wait to test on my real table too.

Comment: Would you please explain what the letter "a" is doing?

Comment: @chikitin "Every derived tables in Mysql MUST have an alias".

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT SUM(C.TOTAL) AS TOTAL_CREDIT FROM (SELECT SUM(A.price) AS TOTAL FROM TABLE1 A WHERE A.acc_id = '555'
UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(B.price) AS TOTAL FROM TABLE2 B WHERE B.account = '555' && B.active='1') C;
```

Comment: Thanks but get this error `Error Code: 1248 \n Every derived table must have its own alias` ... I add a image of my two table

Comment: @root try now. I have updated my query. If it is helpful. Then accept it otherwise, let me know.

Comment: thanks but give error : `Unknown column 'A.price' in 'field list'` , I Accept akhil answer , Thanks all ... That's a horrible problem :-"

Comment: doesn't matter. you would have done something wrong,because i verified the above query. Nevertheless. You got the solution. I'm happy :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  SELECT (t1.price + t2.price) AS TotalCredit 
    FROM TABLE1 AS t1, TABLE2 AS t2 
    WHERE t1.`acc_id` = '555' && t2.`Account`='555' && t2.`Active`='1'
```

EDIT:

here what you looking for  i think

```
 SELECT (SUM(t1.price)+SUM(t2.price) )/2  AS TotalCredit 
FROM Table1 AS t1, Table2 AS t2 
WHERE t1.`acc_id` = '555' && t2.`account`='555' && t2.`active`='1'
```

[**DEMO FIDDLE HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02fdd/1)

Comment: Thanks goodmood , but now give result as array , how to have a one result as SUM ?

Comment: look now my edit and my demo , try to change values in demo and see the result

Comment: Thank too :-" but give back wrong result : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c64ff , test it with changing just one of numbers .

Answer (score 0):

try that

```
SELECT (SUM(t1.price) + SUM(t2.price)) AS TotalCredit 
FROM TABLE1 AS t1, TABLE2 AS t2 
WHERE t1.`acc_id` = '555' && t2.`Account`='555' && t2.`Active`='1'
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
SELECT SUM(a) 
FROM
  (SELECT SUM(price) AS a
   FROM TABLE1 
   WHERE acc_id = '555'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT SUM(price) AS a
   FROM TABLE2 
   WHERE account = '555' && active='1')
```

Comment: Thanks but get this error : `Error Code: 1248 \n Every derived table must have its own alias` on SQLYOG

Answer (score 0):

`Join` could be better. :) Would be even better if you could have showed us the table schema. Here is a solution based on some *assumed sample data*.

Sample data:

Table1:

```
ID  PRICE
11  200
55  300
33  200
44  100
55  500
```

Table2:

```
ID  PRICE   ACTIVE
1   200     0
2   300     1
55  200     0
55  100     1
55  400     1
```

- [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c22d97/1)

Query:

```
select sum(t.price) + x.tb2credit
from tb1 as t
inner join
(SELECT id, SUM(price) AS Tb2Credit 
FROM tb2
WHERE id = 55
and `Active`=1) x
on t.id = x.id
```

Results:

```
SUM(T.PRICE) + X.TB2CREDIT
1300
```

Comment: @root please take a look at the solution here. Please show us your table schema :)

Comment: `acc_id` from TABLE1 and `account` from TABLE2 is must be exact , I've added an image of my tables to first post , review it .

Comment: @root all you need to do is, `sum` table 2 `prices` for the given `acct id` if where `active = 1`. Then add that up to table 1 `sum` for the same `acct id`. That's the logic behind the query I gave. I'll try to use your exact information :)